# Rolling average a certain period using a DAX measure in Power BI

Tags: postgresql, powerbi

I tried generating a DAX measure as a rolling average. I don't quite know how to insert the measure I need rolling averaged as "CPI_annualized". It is not giving an option to bring CPI_annualized into the Rolling Average calc.

This is the error I am given when trying to construct the RollingAverage VAR in the measure P_MA

```
The syntax for 'CALCULATE' is incorrect. DAX(VAR __LAST_DATE = LASTDATE('public econometrics'[date]) ......
```

This is the DAX measure that I am trying to complete :

```
    P_MA = 
VAR __NUM_PERIODS = 3
VAR __LAST_DATE = LASTDATE('public econometrics'[date])
VAR RollingAverage =
    AVERAGEX(
         DATESBETWEEN(
            'public econometrics'[date],
            DATEADD(__LAST_DATE, -__NUM_PERIODS, MONTH),
                __LAST_DATE)
            CALCULATE([CPILFESL]))
)
RETURN RollingAverage
```

This is the DAX measure that I am trying to use in the rolling calculation with the data in my dB given monthly. This works as below.

```
CPI_annualized = (CALCULATE(SUM('public econometrics'[value]),'public 
econometrics'[econometric_name]=="CPILFESL")/CALCULATE(SUM('public 
econometrics'[value]),'public 
econometrics'[econometric_name]=="CPILFESL",SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('public econometrics'[date])))-1
```

Inserting this measure in a line chart gives my this table.

| date | CPILFESL |
| --- | --- |
| 1 January, 1978 | 6.41% |
| 1 February, 1978 | 6.20% |

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting error message due to this line:

```
CALCULATE([CPILFESL])
```

In Dax Calculate measure, you cannot directly calculate a value, instead you have to include a number calculation function such as sum, max, min, here is the example:

```
CALCULATE(sum([CPILFESL]))
```

In addition, you can get rid of Calculate measure when there is no filter expression, such as `sum([CPILFESL])` is enough.

A proper way of using calculate is to filter the value, as shown in online documentation

```
CALCULATE(
    SUM(Sales[Sales Amount]),
    'Product'[Color] = "Blue"
)
```

Comment: I tried the following from your advice. In my P_MA formula I changed the CALCULATE(sum[CPILFESL]) AND CALCULATE(sum[CPI annualized]) AND CALCULATE(SUM('public econometrics'[value]),'public 
econometrics'[econometric_name]="CPILFESL"). It still throws an error saying the calculate is incorrect.

Comment: Is there a typo `CALCULATE(sum[CPILFESL])`, which should be `CALCULATE(sum([CPILFESL]))` as you are missing a closing bracket for sum?

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I settled on CALCULATE([CPI_annualized])  Though, the P_MA does not calculate properly. It gives a constant -0.95. My CPILFESL values are all positive. CPIFESL did not work as it said I cannot use this measure in this calculation.

Comment: Hmm, hope you can figure it out since it is hard to know what is exactly the issue from my side.

Answer (score 0):

You can find many usefull templated here:

https://www.daxpatterns.com/month-related-calculations/

**Moving average 3 months**

```
VAR MonthsInRange = 3
VAR LastMonthRange =
    MAX ( 'Date'[Year Month Number] )
VAR FirstMonthRange =
    LastMonthRange - MonthsInRange + 1
VAR Period3M =
    FILTER (
        ALL ( 'Date'[Year Month Number] ),
        'Date'[Year Month Number] >= FirstMonthRange
            && 'Date'[Year Month Number] <= LastMonthRange
    )
VAR Result =
    IF (
        COUNTROWS ( Period3M ) >= MonthsInRange,
        CALCULATE (
            AVERAGEX ( Period3M, [Sales Amount] ),
            REMOVEFILTERS ( 'Date' )
        )
    )
RETURN
    Result
```